# Regular Expression not working fine

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a regular expression for the format in c#

```
    <abc>-<1wee>-<qwje>-<#>-<weruyu>-<...>-<suidyw>-<xdsljd23>-
```

I write a regular expression of format

```
     Regex r1 = new Regex("(^(<{1}([a-zA-Z0-9]*|[#]|[.]{3})>-{1})*$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

This is working fine in all cases expect 
1. when there is no characters between < and >
eg

```
   <>-<agdf>-
```

2.when any pair of alpha numeric characters comes after<#> and<...>
eg

```
   <abc>-efgh>-<123>-<#>-<...>-
```

this is working fine
but

```
    <abc>-<#>-<123>-<...>-
```

is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This part:

   [a-zA-Z0-9]*

   also matches 0 characters. You probably meant to use `+`
2. your expression says the string *must* terminate with a `-`, which is why the later examples don't work. Try `(-|$)` to make the last dash optional.

Comment: Thanks, First part is working fine. that's my typing mistake actually i want the -. I edited the Question but my problem is whenever the <#> or <...> came as last portion of string it will work. but a pair like<123> is coming last portion(after <#>) it wont work